# Same server, two NICs and two separate networks don't work simultaneously

Tags: networking

I have a debian 10 server with two NICs each connected to two separate networks via static ip (172.16.10.32 and 172.16.30.32) and same subnet mask. The problem I'm having is:
- I can ping 172.16.30.32 from another computer on the .30 network
- I can ping 172.16.10.32 from the same computer on the .30 network (which shouldn't happen)
- I can't ping 172.16.10.32 from any computer on the .10 network (destination host unreachable).

What I want is to have the two networks separate, so I could only reach 172.16.30.32 from the .30 network and 172.16.10.32 from .10 network. From what I understand I need to have a routing table but everything I tried failed.

Comment: Can you add these commands and their result in your question? `ip -br link; ip -br address; ip -br route`. Also please clarify which ping is done from what system (and its IP address). And what is the default gateway of these other systems doing the ping (if they are Linux too, best could be to also give the result of the same commands).

Comment: And, you should also detail your network layout, especially about the routers (those gateways) involved.